# Pygame how to change image collision points

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a matching card game in Pygame and I can render all 52 of my cards in the correct positions but the rects of the images will not change.

I create all my card surfaces using the following method;

```
def generateGrid():
    cardB = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data', 'back.png'))
    for i in range(index):
            grid.append(cardB)
            grid[i] = pygame.transform.scale(cardB, (85,130))
```

and I render my cards by calling the following in the main method;

```
generateGrid()
pos = 25

for i in range(index):
    print(pos)
    if i >0 and i< 14:
        r1 = grid[i].get_rect()
        r1.move_ip(pos,50)
        pos +=95
        background.blit(grid[i], r1)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif i >0 and i<27:
        r2 = grid[i].get_rect()
        pos -=95
        r2.move_ip(pos,195)
        background.blit(grid[i], r2)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif i >0 and i <40:
        r3 = grid[i].get_rect()
        r3.move_ip(pos,350)
        pos +=95

        background.blit(grid[i],r3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif i >0 and i< 53:
        r4 = grid[i].get_rect()
        pos -=95
        r4.move_ip(pos,500)
        background.blit(grid[i],r4)
        pygame.display.update()
    print("Card", i+1, "rendered")
```

Finally in my main loop I try to find which card the mouse is hovering over by doing:

```
for i in range(index):
    if grid[i].get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        print("Colling with:", i)
    else:
        pass
```

My problem is that all the surfaces have the same collision rects: `<rect(0, 0, 85, 130)>`. How can can I change this to match the co-ords of each card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the rectangles associated with images in `grid` don't reflect where the code that renders the cards places them. This can be corrected by creating a parallel list of rectangles which contains this information for each one of them. If this additional list was named `cardPosn`, here's how it could be created:

```
pos = 25
cardPosn = [None] * len(grid)  # preallocate
for i in range(index):
    print(pos)
    if 0 < i < 14:
        r1 = grid[i].get_rect()
        r1.move_ip(pos, 50)
        pos += 95
        background.blit(grid[i], r1)
        cardPosn[i] = r1
        pygame.display.update()
    elif 0 < i < 27:
        r2 = grid[i].get_rect()
        pos -= 95
        r2.move_ip(pos, 195)
        background.blit(grid[i], r2)
        cardPosn[i] = r2
        pygame.display.update()
    elif 0 < i < 40:
        r3 = grid[i].get_rect()
        r3.move_ip(pos, 350)
        pos += 95
        background.blit(grid[i], r3)
        cardPosn[i] = r3
        pygame.display.update()
    elif 0 < i < 53:
        r4 = grid[i].get_rect()
        pos -= 95
        r4.move_ip(pos, 500)
        background.blit(grid[i], r4)
        cardPosn[i] = r4
        pygame.display.update()
    print("Card", i+1, "rendered")
```

Once that's done, a loop for checking for collision points could be written like this:

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
for i in range(index):
    if cardPosn[i] and cardPosn[i].collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        print("Colliding with:", i)
```